# What are the configuration needed from the app end to track app install for google ads app campaign?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-analytics-firebase

Running iOS app promotion universal app campaign on the google ads platform. Campaign is running but there is no impressions on it.

1. I have integrated firebase SDK. "first_open" event will automatically track the app installs.
   Is there any kind of framework and permission needed from the app end ?